# .htaccess help needed for url rewriting for passing parameters after already rewritten url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What my original url look like:

```
localhost/aoc/product.php?pid=2&cname=australia
```

Applied Htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /aoc

RewriteRule ^product-category/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+).html product.php?pid=$1&cname=$2
```

Result Url:

```
localhost/aoc/product-category/1/australia.html
```

But problem I am facing is that how to pass parameter to sort the page items. For ex, let I want to pass variable `?sort=xxx` or `&sort=xxx.` How can it be achieved in the best possible way by editing the htaccess?

```
localhost/aoc/product-category/1/australia.html?sort=xxx  - Not working
localhost/aoc/product-category/1/australia.html&sort=xxx - Not working
```

I don't want the combinations which looks ugly to are below but works after editing the htaccess :

```
http://localhost/aoc/product-category/1/xxx/australia.html

http://localhost/aoc/product-category/1/australia.html/xxx/
```

Please help me explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine old and new query strings, use the QSA (Query String Append) flag

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /aoc

 RewriteRule ^product-category/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+).html product.php?pid=$1&cname=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Wow! That is simply awesome and pinpointed answer to my question. Thanks @starkeen for the great answer.